# Multiview CCA with one source set and multiple independent target sets

Tags: multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis, canonical-correlation

I have 5 datasets from the same subjects that can be interpreted as different data modalities for these subjects. 4 of these datasets describe brain-related data and the last one contains behavioral variables. I would like to test the hypothesis that one can extract correlated latent factors from these datasets, as for example done using Canonical Correlation Analysis. As I have more than 2 datasets, my first idea was to use multiview CCA for this problem but this maximizes the pairwise correlation between all extracted variates. What I am looking for instead is a model that treats the variates extracted from the brain datasets as uncorrelated and only tries to maximize the correlation with the variates in the behavioral set (think of it as one source set and multiple target sets, but treat it as a correlation problem, not a regression problem). I expect, that there is a set of underlying factors in the behavioral dataset that is significantly correlated with **specific factors** from different brain datasets and another set of factors that is correlated with specific factors **from all** brain datasets.

Here's a visualization (note, that its purpose is to give you an intuition for the problem, it might not be accurate):

[image]

I tried to look for papers that describe methods on how to model this in an unsupervised manner. The closest one I could find was [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811921011253#sec0013) but I am not sure if GFA can solve my problem?